# How to extract REST API Response and status code at one time using Rest Assured

Tags: rest, automation

I need to get some fields from the REST API response and the status code as well. I can get only one at a time .

```
Response res = given().header("Content-Type","application/json").body(json).when().post("/rest/auth/1/session").then().extract().response() ;


Integer stC = given().header("Content-Type","application/json").body(json).when().post("/rest/auth/1/session").then().extract().statusCode() ;
```

How can I get both in one request?

Answer (score 3):

As expected, I asked a silly question.

This is how we can get everything from Response object

```
    res.statusCode() ;
    res.headers();
    res.body() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Response res = 
given().header("ContentType", "application/json").body(json).when().post("/rest/auth/1/session");

int statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
```